# arrange numbers 0-9 randomly in opengl circle

Tags: android

I have implemented a circle of numbers from 0-9 in openGL but in sequences, I want a formula to arrange numbers Non-sequential within a circle. i.e for example  4 after 2 then 9  or any numbers follow the others but it must be un sequences.

Please help me as soon as possible!

Comment: I've read that a few times and it's still not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a circle of numbers starting from 0,1,2 until 9, what I need is the numbers be randomize for example starting from 8, 3, 2, 1, 5 and so on.

Comment: my formula for sequence numbers was (x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2);

Comment: can you post the code where you draw these on the screen ?

Comment: Place your numbers in an ArrayList and use the index instead of the number. Then you can shuffle it's content as you like, e.g. via `Collections.shuffle(..)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your numbers in an array, than shuffle them like below

```
 public class ShuffleDemo {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
   // create array list object       
   List arrlist = new ArrayList();

// populate the list 0 to 9
   for(int i = 0, i<=9; i++ ){
     arrlist.add(i);
   }

   System.out.println("Initial collection: "+arrlist); 
   // shuffle the list
   Collections.shuffle(arrlist);

   System.out.println("Final collection after shuffle: "+arrlist);
   }    
}
```

**Doc: [Collections.shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List))**